# I want to know about the flow of this passage

Tags: exam-questions

This a problem from a reading comprehension workbook. The correct answer is (C)(B)(D), but I was wondering if (C)(D)(B) could work as well.

> Instruction: Put items (B), (C), and (D) in the correct order after item (A).
>
> Passage:
>
> (A)Some people seem to have a knack for learning languages. They can pick up new vocabulary, master rules of grammar, and learn to write in the new language more quickly than others. They do not seem to be any cleverer than others, so what makes language learning so much easier for them? Perhaps if we take a close look at these successful language learners, we may discover a few of the techniques which make language learning easier for them.
>
> (B)Therefore, successful learners do not wait for a chance to use the language; they look for such a chance. They find people who speak the language and they ask these people to correct them when they make a mistake. They will try anything to communicate. They are not afraid to repeat what they hear or to say strange things;they are willing to make mistakes and try again. When communication is difficult,they can accept information that is inexact or incomplete. It is more important for them to learn to think in the language than to know the meaning of every word.
>
> (C)First of all, successful language learners are independent learners. They do not depend on the book or the teacher; they discover their own way to learn the language. Instead of waiting for the teacher to explain, they try to find the patterns and the rules for themselves. They are good guessers who look for clues and form their own conclusions. When they guess wrong, they guess again. They try to learn form their mistakes. Successful language learning is active learning.
>
> (D)Above all, successful language learners are learners with a purpose. They want to learn the language because they are interested in the language and the people who speak it. It is necessary for them to learn the language in order to communicate with these people and to learn from them. They find it easy to practice using the language regularly because they want to learn with it.

Answer (score 2):

As well as dan's answer, the "Above all" at the beginning of D suggests that it's the last point being made, since the "all" refers to all the other points, and therefore it has to be the last paragraph coming after all the other points.

Comment: Correct, and "First of all" would place that paragraph at the beginning. There is no actual need to read the paragraphs if you're pushed for time.

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence in C, "**Successful language learning is active learning**,", has the closest connection with the first sentence in B, "**Therefore, successful learners do not wait for a chance to use the language; they look for such a chance**."

So, both "...**do not wait for a chance**..." and "...**look for such a chance**..." are "**active learning**". Therefore, C -> B.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! But I'm still wondering whether the part in (D) that says, "...want to learn the language because they are interested in the language and the people who speak it. It is necessary for them to learn the language in order to communicate with these people and to learn from them," could relate directly to the part in (B) where it says they look for chances to use the language (ex: looking for people who speak the language).

Comment: I realize the "Above all" makes it more natural for (D) to be placed at the end, but I'm more interested in the flow of the content.

Comment: @Annie, I agree that D is relevant to B. That's why we put B->D.